# How to use AJAX in an onclick function to remove content from database

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I'm new to php and the whole web design. I've heard that I can use both php and ajax in this situation and unfortunately I don't know how to use neither. Note that the I've only written two pages, Despesas.php(form) and the Despesa.php(class). The other two pages were not written by me and I was hoping you guys could explain how they were supposed to work(they don't actually) and if the problem is within the pages that I wrote or not.
Here is the code:

Page: Despesas.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/despesa.js">

    </script>

    <form method="post" action="">
            <br/>
            <table>
                <tr><th>IDDespesa</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Metodo</th><th>Local</th><th>Valor</th><th>Data</th><th>Prioridade</th><th>Ações</th></tr>
                <?php
                $resd=Despesa::findAll();
                while ($rowd = $resd->fetch_object()) {
                    $nc=Categoria::findById($rowd->idcat);
                    $rownc=$nc->fetch_object();
                    $nm=Metodo::findById($rowd->idmet);
                    $rownm=$nm->fetch_object();
                    $nl=Local::findById($rowd->idmet);
                    $rownl=$nl->fetch_object();
                    echo'<tr><td>' . $rowd->iddes . '</td><td>' . $rownc->nome . '</td><td>' . $rownm->nome . '</td><td>' . $rownl->nome . '</td><td>' . $rowd->valor . '</td><td>' . $rowd->data . '</td><td>' . $rowd->prior . '</td><td><a onclick="return remDespesa();" href=#"' . $rowd->iddes . '>Remover</a></td></tr>';
                }
                ?>
            </table>
    </form>
```

Here I have a form that reads all the content from the database and fortunately it works as intended. The last column, Ações (Actions) has a link for each row that deletes that Despesa (expense) from the database. Or at least, that's what it should do :P

Page: despesa.js

```
function remDespesa(id) {
    var res = false;
    if (confirm("Deseja apagar despesa?")) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var parms = "operacao=remDesp&id=" + id;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = remDespesaCompleted;
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "controller/apagarDespesa.php");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-WWW-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parms.length);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlHttp.send(parms);
        res = true;
    }
    return(res);
}

function remDespesaCompleted() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var divMsg = document.getElementById("msg");
        var res = this.responseText;
        var obj = JSON.parse(res);
        if (obj.info != undefined) {
            divMsg.innerHTML = obj.info;
            var tabela = document.getElementById(Despesas);
            tabela.innerHTML = obj.tabela;
        } else if (obj.error != undefined) {
            divMsg.innerHTML = obj.error;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ajax code that I've got, I did not write this. I was wondering if you guys could see if it even makes sense. Although I understand the first function, the second one is a completely different story.

Page: apagarDespesa

```
require_once '../class/Despesa.php';

if (isset($_POST['operacao'])) {
    $operacao = $_POST['operacao'];
    if ($operacao == "remDesp"){
        $msg=Despesa::remDesp();
        if(isset($msg['info'])){
        ob_start();

        require "../pages/Despesas.php";
        $msg['tabela']=ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        }


        $str=  json_encode($msg);
        echo $str;
    }
}
```

I understand some things in here :D

To finish, here is the Despesa Class, guess I'll just write the 2 methods used in above:

```
public static function remDesp($id) {
        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $d = new Despesa();
            $d->id = $id;
            $res = $d->delete();
            if ($res) {
                $msg['info'] = 'Despesa Apagada com sucesso';
            } else {
                $msg['error'] = 'Despesa Apagada com sucesso';
            }
        } else {
            $msg['error'] = 'Pedido invalido';
        }
        return ($msg);
    }
public function delete(){
        $db=DB::getInstance();
        $sql="DELETE FROM despesa WHERE iddes=".$this->iddes;
        $res=$db->query($sql);
        return($res);
    }
```

Anyway, any help is gladly accepted.
Thanks for your time.